# What's the difference between using ThreadPool with WaitCallback method vs simple method

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

What's really the difference between option 1 and option 2?

Option 1

```
WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback(PrintMessage);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, "Hello");
```

Option 2

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PrintMessage, "World");
```

Simple method:

```
static void PrintMessage(object obj)
{
   Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: "WaitCallback" is represents the method to be executed.

Option1: WaitCallback is explicitly called, to queue a method for execution. and this method invocation is on a different  thread other than the main thread.

Option2: The .NET framework will wrap the method with WaitCallback. this method invocation is also on a different  thread other than the main thread.

Simple Method: this method calling is executed in the main thread itself.

Comment: So the answer is: there is no difference?